# I am trying to append a parameter like ID to a URL in a SP.UI.ModalDialog Popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog, xml, sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog

I seem to be hitting a wall getting this to work.
I can get the ModalDialog Popup to work but I have spent many hours trying to figure out how to pass a parameter over to the dialog box.

**The Goal:** Is to have the ProductID field to be used a parameter

**The issue:** For some reason 
When either or both of 2 lines from the code below is in the code, the button to open the dialog boxes ceases to work.
These 2 lines

```
args: dialogArgs,

dialogReturnValueCallback: onDialogClosed,`
```

The two above when in the code stops the button form working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=UpqI01Xk841N_9CuQ5wMNuq9zFYl9ThRGFK83kTirNaZpHlB_KtqOQsuq_rvbhkEoKzWx2eHmGUEVuRsRgkhBYN6G4P88iQ7E9317tHeeWCm7WNLlm-efogSztGRwHF4ALZSZgIi48GJ_F2nixLvqYT_d6nONKgdtAa-ZCAL7pf2SnblS9VJ1CfY9irxg7Kw0&amp;t=ffffffffeea0dba9"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>                                                       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>                                                        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type=button onclick="openDialog()">click me</button>
    <div style="display:none">
       <div id="d10">my dialog message</div>
    </div>
    <script>
    function openDialog() {
     var e = document.getElementById('d10');
      var dialogArgs = {
       itemID:e.id
        var options = {
        title: "My Dialog Title",
        url : "url = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/publishing/product.aspx",
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        showClose: true,
        allowMaximize: false,
        autoSize: true,
        **args: dialogArgs,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: onDialogClosed,**
        html: e.cloneNode(true)
       };
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Once I got that working , what code should I use for the dialog please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came across this post that answered my question. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: put some more info so it will help to others